# Getting an error about duplicate values in my Web.config when it was working fine earlier

Tags: .net, iis-7

The other day, we got an updated copy of an ongoing rewrite of our main application from a third party performing the rewrite.

I was primarily using it as a reference for the code I have already and was just implementing something from this updated copy in a different project of ours.

This morning, I decided to overwrite my existing copy of this rewrite with the new version of the rewrite. Ran it and was getting all kinds of problems.

Restored the backup I created prior to updating, and now I get this error when I launch my application:

> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Elmah'

On line 10 of my web.config I do have this:

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
    ...
</sectionGroup>
```

With a handful of of nodes belonging to it. Then further down, I do also have this:

```
<add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

The thing is though, this was working perfectly fine literally 15 minutes ago before I deleted the contents of this folder and replaced them with the contents of the updated code.

I then deleted the contents of the folder containing the update, and unzipped the backup I created into the original root folder. Now when I run it I get that error. If I simply comment out that node, I get other similar errors about duplicate nodes.

I also had a coworker, whose code is functional, send me her web.config and it's identical to mine (a few values contain her email address instead of mine, but that's the only difference).

Any ideas what might be causing this behavior...?

Using .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2013, IIS 7.5.7600.16385

Comment: Always remove it first and then add. That avoids duplication. Check the parent level to see where the duplicate item comes from.

Comment: If I comment that out, it gives me another duplicate node. Comment that, gives me another. Comment that, gives me another. Do a Ctrl-F for any of them (aside from the very first one which I describe in my question) and they appear only once in this Web.config

Comment: there is a `<remove>` tag if you check documentation. I don't ask you to comment yours out.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a backup of a Web.config file for a different solution and moved it up to the root `wwwroot` folder.

Turns out all applications inherit any settings on the server itself, so I guess it was just appending the application's `Web.config` file to that root `Web.config`, causing it see duplicates. Ugh.

Found solution via http://forums.iis.net/t/1158851.aspx?Problem+with+Cannot+add+duplicate+collection+entry+of+type+add+with+unique+key+attribute+name+set+to+ScriptHandlerFactory

> The website will inherits the settings form parent level . This should be the reason of this issue. You can check if there is a web.fig file in the parent web content folder(e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\someFolder\ or **C:\inetpub\wwwroot**) and an duplicate collection entry in it.